# How do I notice if my Windows pc is booted with WOL

Tags: windows, boot, wake-on-lan

i have Windows 8.1 (x64) as OS. I want to start an Apache Server if my PC is booted via WOL. So my first attempt was to write a small program which starts every time in the autostart, this should perform a check if the PC was booted over WOL and if this is true it should start the apache. But how do I notice if my PC was booted via WOL? Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

I would look to somehow incorporate [powercfg](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx) into your program.  In particular, use the "lastwake" flag.  You'll probably need to force a WOL and then check it with Powercfg to see how it is reported.

Comment: It says both times "0".

Comment: Doesn't work, there is no difference in the lastwake flag.

Comment: Try using "powercfg -devicequery wake_armed" to see what devices are allowed to wake the pc.